# Remove Lines in Multiple .txt files (that start with 1 2 3 4 5) in Python

Tags: python

> *** NOTE :::I have very little knowlege and programming background***

## **What i want :**

I want to remove lines in txt files that start with **1 2 3 4 or 5** and keep only lines that start with **0**

I have **9032 txt files** in a folder and i want a python script to run in that folder and do all my line removal work...

here is sample of text file data image
[image]

i want output like this
[image]

the code i wrote ... (ofcourse not working at all... wrong logics)

```html
import os
import re
import glob


direc = r"C:\Users\hassa\Desktop\yolo_ssd_test"

os.chdir(direc)

yolo_files = os.listdir(direc)


file_count = 0

for file_name in yolo_files:

    file_count = file_count + 1
    # print(file_count,file_name)

for txt in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), txt), 'r+') as input_append_file:
        text = input_append_file.read()
        for line in text:
            if not line.startswith("1"):  
               # line = line.replace('.' , '')
               input_append_file.write(line)

        for line in text:
            if not line.startswith("2"):  
               # line = line.replace('.' , '')
               input_append_file.write(line)

        for line in text:
            if not line.startswith("3"):  
               # line = line.replace('.' , '')
               input_append_file.write(line)

        for line in text:
            if not line.startswith("4"):  
               # line = line.replace('.' , '')
               input_append_file.write(line)
```

Some one please help me write a code for multiple files

Comment: Please edit your post to contain code as text, rather than using [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: This would be faster and easier using the `findstr` command line tool.

Comment: How does your code not work? Do you get an error?

Comment: The code you've posted does something entirely different.  `input_append_file.read()` reads the entire file as a single string.  It doesn't do line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made this way more complicated than it should be.

```
for txt in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    lines = open(txt,'r').readlines()
    lines = [l for l in lines if l and l[0] == '0']
    open(txt,'w').writelines(lines)
```

Comment: this works only if there are no empty lines and 0 is really the only accepted line (it's not clear from the question)

Comment: Thankyou So Much... IT WORKED... I donot know what was i doing xD

Comment: The comment about empty lines is a good one.  I'm going to fix that.